# How to display name of songs on SD using CursorAdapter?

Tags: java, android, cursor, android-cursoradapter

I am trying to build a music player application. I am trying to display song names from sd card of the virtual device.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG="message";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.i(TAG,"onCreate STarted");


        Log.i(TAG,"listAdapterTo be Initilized");

        final Cursor  c = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,new String[]{MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME},null,null,null);
        ListAdapter songAdapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(this,c);

        Log.i(TAG,"ListAdapterSuccessfull");

        ListView lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        lv.setAdapter(songAdapter);

        Log.i(TAG,"success");

    }

    public class CustomCursorAdapter  extends CursorAdapter{

        private static final String TAG="message";
        LayoutInflater mInflater;

        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
            Log.i(TAG,"newView");
            View customView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row,parent,false);
            return customView;
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
            Log.i(TAG,"BindVIew");
            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv);
            textView.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME)));
        }

        public CustomCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, LayoutInflater mInflater) {
            super(context, c);
            this.mInflater = mInflater;
        }
    }
}
```

The application crashes when I run it and `cursorAdapter` isn't even called.

> Information:Gradle tasks [:app:incrementalDebugSupportDex]
>   :app:buildInfoDebugLoader
>   :app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
>   /home/krozen/AndroidStudioProjects/CorverArtEx/app/src/main/java/com/example/krozen/corverartex/MainActivity.java
>   Error:(29, 35) error: constructor CustomCursorAdapter in class
>   CustomCursorAdapter cannot be applied to given types; required:
>   Context,Cursor,LayoutInflater found: MainActivity,Cursor reason:
>   actual and formal argument lists differ in length Note:
>   /home/krozen/AndroidStudioProjects/CorverArtEx/app/src/main/java/com/example/krozen/corverartex/CustomCursorAdapter.java
>   uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with
>   -Xlint:deprecation for details. Incremental compilation of 2 classes completed in 0.732 secs. :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
> > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details. Information:BUILD FAILED Information:Total time: 3.519 secs
> >     Information:2 errors Information:0 warnings Information:See complete
> >     output in console

Comment: Post the stacktrace of exception.

Comment: You are missing the third argument in `new CustomCursorAdapter(this,c)`

Comment: You can use: `LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);` and `new CustomCursorAdapter(this, c, li);`

Comment: @AllanPereira gives an error LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context); undefined "context"

Comment: LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);

Comment: @AllanPereira Solved!!
Thanks.. But i have a query
It gives exception and crashes when I use following code
        String[] projection = new String[]{MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE};
        Cursor  cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,projection,null,null,null);
But it works perfectly when I use following code
Cursor curose = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null);Why?